# Is it possible to create data-driven URLs in Django?

Tags: django, django-urls

I'm thinking of how in Wordpress one can create pages, including parent/child relationships between them, from which it can construct URLs like:

```
example.com/my-custom-page
example.com/my-parent/a-child-page
```

... and I'm wondering how it would be possible to craft the URLconf in Django to do the same.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can the question be elaborated some more?

Answer (score 1):

Check django's [urlconf docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#url-dispatcher).

An example:

```
# URLconf
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^blog/$', 'blog.views.page'),
    url(r'^blog/page(?P<num>\d+)/$', 'blog.views.page'),
)

# View (in blog/views.py)
def page(request, num="1"):
    # Output the appropriate page of blog entries, according to num.
    ...
```

In your case the dynamic param, would be what looks like a page slug, which you would then look up using.

Comment: What if I don't want to prefix it with "blog"?  Can I simply create a route like: url(r'^$', 'blog.views.page') and use it to parse the path (e.g., /my-custom-page or /my-parent/a-child-page) for the specific page to be displayed?  I'm also assuming such a route would need to go at the bottom of my URLconf.

Comment: You really should read the docs. They will answer all these questions you are having.